# Error (Code 1034) : Load data error

Tags: mysql, key, tmp

My current version of mysql  is 5.0.77. I created a database and is trying to load my data into the MyISAM tables with the "load data infile" command. The data are ~3.5GB in size.

I encounter this error while loading:-

> Error (Code 3): Error writing file '/tmp/STH06V6g' (Errcode: 28)
>
> Error (Code 1034): 28 when fixing table
>
> Error (Code 1034): Number of rows changed from 106558636 to 237525263

When i check /var/logs/mysqld.log, it displays this warning:-

> 120420 9:33:10 [Warning] Warning: Enabling keys got errno 28 on sample.X004,retrying

I did a df -h to check on my file usage:-

> Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
>
> /dev/mapper/KusuVolGroup00-VAR
>
> 2.0G  1.6G  342M  82% /var

I did not enable/disable any keys prior to loading. May I know how do I go about this error?

Thank you so much in advance!

Joanne

Comment: You're trying to put a 3.5gb data in to a file system of 2gb?

Comment: Actually, after the database was created, the physical folder was mv to another path with higher storage capacity and symlinked back to /var. Previously I managed to load files of 2.5Gb into the database and it worked.

Comment: Then please show the new location and its space availability as pointed out below, its telling you it ran out of space

Comment: OK.The new location has 22 Tb of storage availability. My current physical database folder is 510 Gb in that path.

Comment: Then your problem is that mySQL is looking somewhere else for the data, as error 28 is clearly "no space left on device" .. its run out..

Comment: I suspect it is the /temp file where mysql writes to. The physical database folder is symlinked, but I did not redirect the tempdir. Thanks for your inputs btw! :)

Answer (score 0):

Error code 28 means "no space left on device".